# How to remove the error-syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 16

Tags: php, html, mysql

> The code is as follows-:The error is in the line having  and
>    tags.

```
echo "<tr><td>".Email."</tr></td>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['username']."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['email']."</td></tr>"; 
        echo "<tr><td><button><a href='delete.php?id=".<?php $row['id']?>."'>delete</a></button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this you concat the values wrongly near `<?php $row['id']?>` and `"<tr><td>".Email."</tr></td>"`

```
echo "<tr><td>Email</tr></td>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['username']."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['email']."</td></tr>"; 
        echo "<tr><td><button><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>delete</a></button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using php tag inside echo. this should

```
echo "<tr><td><button><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>delete</a></button></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the string properly instead of outputting $row['id'], like this:

```
echo "<tr><td><button><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}'>delete</a></button></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've got a PHP opening tag `<?php ... ?>` when you're already in the PHP context. Just change this to

```
echo "<tr><td><button><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>delete</a></button></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tags. In the first line replace `tr` with `td` and `td` with `tr`.